# Oracle Database Implicit Precision Conversion During Number Arithmetic

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Trying to find documentation that details what happens when I perform arithmetic on Numbers of different precision:

e.g. Number(5,2) + Number(6,3) = Number(?, ?)

Looking for the rules that dictate this conversion for addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division.

Scoured the Oracle documentation, but could only find info on implicit conversion from Float/Double/Char to Number, not between Numbers of different precision.

Comment: The result will just be a plain, unconstrained number; unless/until you cast it to a constrained type, or try to put it into a constrained column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data type will be `NUMBER`:

```
CREATE TABLE t
AS
SELECT CAST(1 AS Number(5,2)) + CAST(1 AS Number(6,3)) AS r 
FROM dual;
```

Checking metadata:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, data_precision, data_scale
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'T';

┌─────────────┬──────────────┬────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────┐
│ TABLE_NAME  │ COLUMN_NAME  │ DATA_TYPE  │ DATA_PRECISION  │ DATA_SCALE │
├─────────────┼──────────────┼────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────┤
│ T           │ R            │ NUMBER     │                 │            │
└─────────────┴──────────────┴────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────┘
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=49bc056897e185ab08aabb9ee2282c71)**

Comment: I am interested in knowing the precision of the result. e.g. when I add 1.1 + 1.01, the result is as precise as the most precise input (2.11). When I multiply 1.1 * 1.01, the result is as precise as the sum of the inputs' precisions (1.111). And when I divide 1 / 3, the result seems to have the maximum allowed precision.

Comment: @Benitok The result of arithmetic operation will be NUMBER: `A decimal number with up to 38 significant digits in the range of -(10**125) to +(10**125).`

Comment: @Benitok Simple example - adding 0 to column https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=54c2027a15eacec8f62441ad372fa76b will change `NUMBER(x,y)` to `NUMBER`